# How to implement AutoLogin Interface correctly, Liferay 6.2

Tags: java, liferay-6, autologin

When I try to implement the mentioned interface I found that there are 2 methods to override.

1. doLogin
2. doHandleException

can anyone please explain how to implement those methods in a proper way.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the source code of below liferay class and same you can implement to your Auto login..

[RememberMeAutoLogin](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/security/auth/RememberMeAutoLogin.java)

Please have a look into following link for more liferay stuff [LiferaySavvy.com](http://LiferaySavvy.com)